# Checking if an element is inside an array contained within an object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I have an object which contains an array of objects like

```
{ 
    0: [
          { value:1}
          { value:2}
          { value:3}

       ]
}
```

I am trying to check if an element is inside the array, so what i'm doing i'm looping over it like 
`Object.values(object).some(el => el.value === someNumber)` but it always returns false, anyone has any ideea why? `someNumber` can be anything, it's a dynamic value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to check `el` that is actualy array with `someNumber`, that I supposed is number. To do what you whant you need to smth like this:

```js
const obj = { 
  0: [
    { value:1},
    { value:2},
    { value:3}
 ]
}

const someNumber = 2;
const result = Object.values(obj).some((arr) => arr.some((el) => el.value === someNumber));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another level, because `Object.values` returns an array of an array.

```js
var object = { 0: [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }] };

console.log(Object.values(object).some(values => values.some(el => el.value === 2)));
console.log(Object.values(object).some(values => values.some(el => el.value === 7)));
```

Comment: You made a mistake : `values => some` should be `values => values.some`

Answer (score 2):

The array is in the `[0]` element of the object, so you should use `object[0]`, not `Object.values(object)`.

```js
const object = { 
  0: [
    { value:1},
    { value:2},
    { value:3}
 ]
}

console.log(object[0].some(el => el.value === 1));
console.log(object[0].some(el => el.value === 6));
```

Unless your object can contain more properties and you want to search all of them. Then the other answers are more correct.